# How to add style to selector via jquery.?

Tags: jquery, html, css, styles

Will the following code work?

```
var htmlattri="background-color:red;";
$('a').css("style",htmlattri);
```

If not, what is the correct solution?

Comment: LOL... The same 8 answers...

Comment: Make sure you read the [docs for `.css()`](http://api.jquery.com/css/).

Answer (score 36, accepted):

You could add it to the `style` attribute:

```
$('a').attr('style', htmlattri);
```

But I would use `.css()`:

```
$('a').css('background-color', 'red');
```

Or better yet, do it with a stylesheet and just use `.addClass()`.

Comment: Perfect! `.addClass()` is what I'm looking for. Is there a way to remove all classes before adding one, without having to know all of them and removing one by one?

Comment: I think answer to my question is [clearly documented](http://api.jquery.com/removeClass/#entry-longdesc).

Answer (score 3):

You were almost there. You have to give the parameter name and value seperately: `$('a').css("background-color","red");`

Answer (score 2):

Try this:

```
$("a").css("background-color","red");
```

Or

```
var style ="background-color:red;";
$("a").attr("style", style);
```

Answer (score 2):

Use this

```
$('a').css('background-color','red');
```

OR you can use also this type

```
$('a').css({background-color:'red'});
```

Answer (score 1):

You can directly achieve this by doing this:

```
    $('a').css("background-color",red);
```

But you shouldn't do this directly on hyperlink. You should create a class or Id and add that class CSS on particular class or id.

HTML:-

```
   <a href="#" class="link" id="link">Test</a>
```

Jquery:-

```
   $('#link').css("background-color",red);
```

Answer (score 0):

try the following code:

`$('a').css('background-color','red');`

Answer (score 0):

```
$('a').css('backgroundColor': 'red');
```

Answer (score 0):

This doesn't use jQuery but allows adding style to a document.

```
var styleSheet = document.createElement( 'STYLE' ) ;
styleSheet.innerHTML += '.myclass{ color:red; }' ;
styleSheet.innerHTML += '.yourclass{ color:blue; }' ;
document.body.appendChild( styleSheet ) ;
```

See https://www.w3.org/wiki/Dynamic_style_-_manipulating_CSS_with_JavaScript